# Plot double line chart from jSON file with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to plot the following format in a double line chart with JSON having the following format:

```
"217.29.66.127": {
    "1438417200": {
      "count_a_10": 0, 
      "count_w_10": 0
    }, 
    "1438417201": {
      "count_a_10": 0, 
      "count_w_10": 0
    }, 
    "1438417202": {
      "count_a_10": 1, 
      "count_w_10": 0
    }
}
```

I would like to have on my x axis the time values: 1438417200, 1438417201, 1438417202.

And on my y-axis, the a counts for on line and the w count for the second line.

Should I reformat my json file or is there an easy way to do that?
Highcharts expert wanted here :(

Comment: What code you tried so far?

Comment: As far from now, I can't go nowhere as I have a 3 layer of data: IP, time, 2 types of data. And no experience on highcharts, I don't know how to formulate it in series data. A hint would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Try this one [GoJS](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html)

Comment: Yeah,  I think you should reformat the "ip"  object into array (use Object.keys)  then you probably can take advantage of Array.map to do your staff

Comment: Do you have a default interval between data points? From the data sample seems like 1ms is it always like that?